Group Policy: stop default Office Suite save locations to OneDrive
I have received a request to change the default office suite save locations from one drive to a folder on their local machines.
So far I have tried:
Registry edit for PerferCloudSaveLocations in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General to 0. That did not work.
Picture of group policy
Changing the administrative template for the specific office programs. I have tried changing the "Default file location" for excel to a local folder on their computer but that didn't work Picture of that. I have seen other options when googling to change the default save location but they are not in mine. I updated the latest Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML) for Microsoft 365 Apps (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) but that did not change it. If there are other ones to look for, please send them over. I have basically looked through every option in the Administrative templates and nothing has worked so far.
